# Python scheduler using bat file

Tags: python, batch-file

I have got a python script for reading a CSV file from a server, extracts one line and send an email with the extracted line. But I would like to run the script every 20 minutes which is the time step for updated the csv file.
I think the best way is to launch a `.bat` script

Here is my `.bat` script

```
@echo off
python  C:\Users\.....\mypythonScript.py %*
```

I have made a simple one that runs the python script but I´d like to repeat it every 20 minutes.

Comment: Use the windows scheduler.

Comment: window sheduler permits task for a day

Comment: Nope. You can have it repeat with any duration.